# How to Merge the results of a $match and $geoNear in one pipeline in Mongodb

Tags: php, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of restaurants and I want to query them with two diffrent criterias and merge them together

I have two aggregation pipelines one that is a $match and the other one that is a $geoNear ,

```
 array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "$match" => array:1 [▼
      "$or" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:1 [▼
          "$and" => array:2 [▼
            0 => array:1 [▼
              "country" => array:1 [▶]
            ]
            1 => array:1 [▼
              "$or" => array:1 [▼
                0 => array:1 [▼
                  "$or" => array:1 [▶]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

and

```
^ array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "$geoNear" => array:5 [▼
      "near" => array:2 [▶]
      "distanceField" => "distance.calculated"
      "spherical" => true
      "key" => "location"
      "query" => array:1 [▶]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I want to be able to make just one call/ in one pipeline and get  **ALL NON DUPLICATES** restaurants. (a way to identify them it would be with the _id )

For example getting all the ones that match $match pipeline , the same with $geoNear , merge them and remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You can use `query` option in `$geoNear`. It will include the documents which matches the condition in query.

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/)

Sample from documentation:

```
db.places.aggregate([
   {
     $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.99279 , 40.719296 ] },
        distanceField: "dist.calculated",
        maxDistance: 2,
        query: { category: "Parks" }, //Query portion
        includeLocs: "dist.location",
        spherical: true
     }
   }
])
```

Comment: as you can see the geoNear already has a query , the thing is that the conditions are different , for example when doing the geoNear the key state is open and when I'm doing the $match the key state is closed

Comment: ok, can we speak with sample documents and expected response? I feel that some misunderstanding is there

Comment: {
            'state': 'open' // closed, N/A
            'name': 'burger king',
            'location': {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : {
                    18.251985,
                    57.60289589999999
                }
            }
        }
  I'm going to simplify it (the real query is more complex) i want to get all restaurant that are open checking the location ($geoNear) and then all the restaurants that are either closed or N/A using the ($match )

Comment: Do you have multiple entries per restaurant then?